# Passport LocalStrategy inconsistent class name

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I'm creating a strategy object like this :

```
var strat = new LocalStrategy({
            usernameField: 'email'
        },
        function(username, password, done) {
            User.findOne({ email: username }, function (err, user) {
                if (err) { return done(err); }
                // Return if user not found in database
                if (!user) {
                    return done(null, false, {
                        message: 'User not found'
                    });
                }
                // Return if password is wrong
                if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
                    return done(null, false, {
                        message: 'Password is wrong'
                    });
                }
                // If credentials are correct, return the user object
                return done(null, user);
            });
        }
    );
```

In my debugger, I see that the strat object is an instance of Class "Strategy".

[image]

Shouldn't it be an instance of "LocalStrategy" since it was created via LocalStrategy conscructor ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is an example piece of code of what is normally do to setup passportjs using local strategy

```
var LocalStrategy   = require('passport-local').Strategy;
```

As you can see Strategy is the name of the exported symbol and [the name of the strategy constructor](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local/blob/master/lib/strategy.js). `LocalStrategy` is just the name of a local variable you are using.